# Is it possible and reasonable to use AMEs for interpretation in a logistic regression even if the spline methodology is to be used?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, splines, marginal-effect

Because of the linearity assumption of the logistic regression I have to use splines for my regression.
I am now wondering if I should still use AMEs to extend the results?

I am working with R. I know the function margins(). But this function does not work with my spline modell.

```
SplineModell <- glm(y ~ ns(x1, df = 4) + ns(x2, df = 4) + ... ,
          family = binomial("logit"))
```

Is it possible and reasonable to use AMEs (average marginal effects) for interpretation in a logistic regression even if the spline methodology is to be used?

Unfortunately, I have not found any exact literature on this.
I would be very grateful for an answer.

Comment: What makes marginal effects useful in this context?  Estimates on the linear predictor scale can be made without the use of complex interactions as required on the absolute risk scale.  Don't you want a partial effect plot instead?  These are easy to get for logistic regression using the R `rms` package `Predict` and `plot, ggplot, plotp` functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
I don't know much about statistics. But well, then I will continue without AMEs.
Do you know any (good) literature on partial effect plots?
(Maybe even with examples of logistic spline regressions)

Comment: Lots of examples in my [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rms) book and course notes.  See especially the three chapters on binary logistic regression.

Comment: Great! Thanks! And if I want to use predicted values instead of log odds, should I use these codes?
`SplineModell <- glm(y ~ ns(x1, df =2), family = binomial("logit"))`

`predictions <- predict(SplineModell, type = "response")`
                 
`frame <- data.frame(x1 = SplineModell$model$ns(x1, df = 2), pred = predictions)`
                           
`ggplot(frame, aes(x =x1, y = pred)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.33) + geom_smooth()`

Comment: `require(rms);dd <- datadist(mydata);options(datadist='dd');f <- lrm(y ~ rcs(x1, 4) + rcs(x2, 3) + x3); ggplot(Predict(f))`